# htaccess 301 redirect error

Tags: .htaccess

i have setup up a redirect

RedirectMatch 301 /data(.*) http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datassheets$1

and i am getting the following error 
http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datasheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheetssheets/doc3542.pdf
when i rename the datasheets directory to something else it works but this is not an option

is this an apache error or am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RedirectMatch regular expression `/data(.*)` is matching on every request and thus will continue indefinitely.

What the complete redirect rule will look like depends on your use-case. The following rule takes care of the endless loop issue and redirects the content following */data/* to the new structure at *http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datasheets/*.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/data/(.+) http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datassheets/$1
```

> /data/**my-cool-file** =>
>   http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datassheets/**my-cool-file**

Answer (score 0):

the `(.*)` portion that you have after `/data` is matching `sheets` in your url. You are then taking that match and appending it on the redirect. That's what's giving you the repeating word. I'm guessing you're also redirecting to your own site, which is why it's repeating so many times.

What are you expecting to come after data that you want to append to the redirect? If it's a query string, you can add `[QSA]` as a flag at the end to maintain the query string.

Example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /data/(.*) http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/datassheets/$1 [QSA]
```

Also, consider that you are telling everyone that any page that starts with `data` in any directory shouldn't exist, yet you are redirecting them to a page that matches the very same pattern you are supposedly getting rid of. You probably need to expand the regex to only match what you intend.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer this is not quite working the doc name is not a query string

Comment: @Terry In that case, can you please elaborate on what you are expecting to come after "data" that you want to append to the redirect?

Comment: Yes thanks for your respones so i have a directory with a lot of pdf file i want to reditect any user who has book marked that specific pdf from the old site and redirect them to the new directory where the file exisist

Comment: I've updated my answer to take that into account. All you really need to do is add a slash to your regex.